# Expression of different type expected

Tags: ocaml

I have the following code:

```
    type point  = { x : float; y : float; z : float }
    type dpoint = { dx : float; dy : float; dz : float }
    type physical_object = { position : point; velocity : dpoint }
    let move p dp = {x = p.x + dp.x; y = p.y + dp.y; z = p.z + dp.z}
```

I am getting this error:

```
File "code.ml", line 4, characters 21-24:
Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type
         int
```

`p.x` is highlighted

Why is this?
Am I not referencing the record's fields correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator `+` has type `int -> int -> int` and thus is applicable only for the values of type `int`. Use `+.` operator for floats, (and `*.`, `/.` correspondingly for other operations).

OCaml doesn't have operator overloading (aka [ad hoc polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism)), as it doesn't play well with type inference. However, it makes your code much more explicit, that can be considered a benefit.

Answer (score 2):

In OCaml, `+` works on integers only. For floats you have to use the `+.` operator (that's with a dot suffix). For more details, see e.g. http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html.